# Printing the version that is currently used with parse.com

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'd like to print the parse.com (Framework) version if my iOS App starts.

I've neither found something about how to print the version within the docs, nor have I found anything with google..

Thanks

Comment: I check documentation too but found nothing. Could you tell me why do you need to print parse framework version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the current version of parse using the `PARSE_API_VERSION` constant, like so:

```
NSLog(@"Parse Framework API Version = %ld", (long)PARSE_API_VERSION);
```

Or if you're looking for the Swift version:

```
println("Parse Framework API Version = \(PARSE_API_VERSION)")
```